# Querying two levels of related data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a Payment and a TransactionsGroup model. They are related via a BelongsToMany relationship.

The TransactionGroup is also related to Transactions via HasMany.

I want to get the Payments and related transactions. How would I do this using Eloquent? I've got this far:

```
    $payments = Payment::with('transactionGroups')->findOrFail($paymentId);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load nested relations with the following code:

```
$payments = Payment::with('transactionGroups', 'transactionGroups.transactions')->findOrFail($paymentId);
```

Eloquent will load **transactionGroups** for given payment and then for each of them it will load related transactions. You can later access them the following way:

```
foreach ($payment->transactionGroups as $transactionGroup) {
  foreach ($transactionGroup->transactions as $transaction) {
    // your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly (as soon as I remembered to add the related data to my visible array) :P .